# need to get string with OS name

Tags: c#, scom

I'm using SCOM 2012 and trying to insert a custom event. I am creating an instance of `ManagementPackClassCriteria` like this:

```
ManagementPackClassCriteria classCriteria = 
    new ManagementPackClassCriteria("Name = 'Microsoft.Windows.Server.2008.Computer'");
```

But a null result returned. I know that computer I wanted to collect data from is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. How should I specify its name? Or how I can get this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Environmen class, which has OsVersion Property. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).

Comment: It returns not actually that i need(I was trying)